# Unity5 assignment params before update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I have 3 C# scripts in my project
A is a class extends MonoBehaviour, I put it on a prefab.
B is not a mono class,it include some logic methods.
C is a test class, i will instantiate gameobjects in this class.

The question is: I want to assign B to A ,because A will call B.OnFixedTick() in FixedUpdate.
But if i code like this in class C (NOT CORRECT)

```
A.Instantiate(position,rotation);
A.GetComponent<B>().SetB(B);
```

The first Fixed-Tick in A will cause exception,because A.B is null.
Is the only way to code this in A.FixedUpdate()?

```
FixedUpdate(){if(B!=null)B.OnFixedTick(this);}
```

or is there any way to set B to A safety?

I'm sorry for my mistake but the first code block not correct.
There is the correct code below

```
GameObject obj = B.Instantiate(position,rotation);
obj.GetComponent<A>.SetB(B)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing where you call `A.GetComponent<B>().SetB(B);`? For example, calling it in the `Start()` or `Awake()` of `A` instead?

Comment: I think i can't because the gameobject was instantiated in B.Instantiate (),maybe a lot of B in my code(like B1,B2,B3 all of these extends from B).But there only one A, so I don't know whitch B the code need in A.Start()

Answer (score 0):

A.GetComponent() will only work if B is a component. By far the most common type of component is MonoBehaviour and you stated that B is not a MonoBehaviour.
If B is just an ordinary C# class the easiest way to assign it is in A.Awake

B = new B();

Or your could do the same thing in class C

A.B = new B();

There are of course many other ways of assigning a value to a property depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i think i have some idea for this